# Saving debugging state and backwards debugging with Xcode or friends

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, gdb

I am using Xcode in order to debug C++ programs. The main problem for me is that it takes around 10 munutes till the program gets to the point of the program that I need to debug. Then I realize about something inspecting the variables and some other stuff, and modify the code. Then 15 minutes again and so ...

I wonder if there is possible in some way in Xcode or in another IDE or compiler/debugger for C++, to "save" in some way a desired debugging state of the program. So if my compouter crashes or I modify the code and make some mistakes, one can open this saved state instantly and get fast to the point where one left before.

I also wonder if at this moment Xcode can "backwards debugging". GDB can for sure, as for september 2009. Or what do you think is the best IDE to do this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

GDB has "backwards debugging" (or more correctly "Reverse Debugging") for a limited number of platforms (list of native supported ones):

- i386-linux
- amd64-linux
- moxie-elf  ( http://moxielogic.org/blog/ )

So it is impossible for now to use this functionality on Mac OS X, with Xcode or without it.

Answer (score 0):

Saving of program state in offline is very hard task. It is almost impossible to restore state of file descriptors, network connections, memory state (randomization of layout), even pid.

Such task is related to "Live migration" problem in openvz.

Answer (score 0):

"Edit and Continue" feature from MSVS allow you to continue running after breakpoint with new version of code. It is supported for `C#`, `C++` and `Basic`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esaeyddf(VS.80).aspx